# React Redux: How to complete function only after Redux state is updated?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, redux, react-redux

I have a function that creates a new GeoJson layer:

```
  function makeLayer(data) {
    dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_COLOR_DOMAIN", payload: data });
    var COLOR_SCALE = scaleThreshold()
      .domain(colorDomain)
      .range([
        [209, 238, 234],
        [168, 219, 217],
        [133, 196, 201],
        [104, 171, 184],
        [79, 144, 166],
        [59, 115, 143],
        [42, 86, 116],
      ]);

    return new GeoJsonLayer({
      data: data,
      getFillColor: (f) => COLOR_SCALE(f.properties.v),
    });
  }
```

I want to change the fill color based on `data`, which is data returned from an async function. Currently, a new GeoJson layer is created and returned before `colorDomain` is updated via the `UPDATE_COLOR_DOMAIN` redux function. I'm using Redux hooks, hence the `dispatch` function.

How can I modify the above function to ensure that `colorDomain`, and thus `COLOR_SCALE`, is updated before a new GeoJson layer is created?

**Update:**

`colorDomain` comes from the `useSelector` hooks:

```
const colorDomain = useSelector((state) => state.map.colorDomain);
```

`data` comes from `asyncFunc`, which I mapped over an array of ids inside a `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const populateArray = async () => {
    const newArr = await Promise.all(
      ids.map(async (element) => {
        const data = await asyncFunc(element.value);
        return { layer: makeLayer(data) };
      })
    );
    setLayers([...layers, ...newArr]);
  };
  populateArray();
}, [variables]);
```

Comment: Where is the asynchronous work happening currently? And where is `colorDomain` coming from?

Comment: @timotgl gave additional info in the update

Comment: So dispatching `UPDATE_COLOR_DOMAIN` causes a reducer to mutate `state.map.colorDomain` but your function `makeLayer` continues to execute with an outdated value of `colorDomain`?

Comment: @timotgl exactly

Comment: If you really need to update state while this `ids.map` iteration is running, an async middleware like thunk would help, since it provides a `getState` function which allows to get the up-to-date state on demand, in the middle of coordinating async stuff. Alternatively you could move the reducer logic for `UPDATE_COLOR_DOMAIN` into `makeLayer` so you don't depend on the selector being updated.

Comment: The fact that you depend on `state.map.colorDomain` having been computed for every loop iteration makes your whole batch operation a bit complicated. Ideally you would already know the value for `colorDomain` before calling `makeLayer`. If the reducer that handles `UPDATE_COLOR_DOMAIN` is looking at some other state, consider adding a selector for that part of the state you so have all you need *in* the component. Then you can do one final update of `state.map.colorDomain` after all the layers have been computed.